# Create a condition maker using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a condition maker like in the [image: picture] I have tried multiple select input boxes. [selectize](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) [select2](https://select2.org/) but nothing seems to fit the requirements.

- The condition like in the image a dropdown should show LHS operands, operator shall also come from another dropdown.
- After that the RHS may be written manually.
- But one single condition should look like one tag, which can be edit later if user wants to.

Any help?

Comment: this sounds more like a taglist component instead, with custom styling for operators.

Comment: Sorry I am noob in js, can you point me to a direction.

Comment: This is a way too vague question for stackoverflow, just search "javascript tag list component" in google, you will find ton of components that does this. After understanding the component, you can come back to this post and read my above comment, you will understand what I mean. Stackoverflow is meant for specific questions, though, while your is a (quite) vague one that doesn't fit in this network. Just to help you searching a bit, you might want to use this: https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for taking time to explain, but i think select2(mentioned in the question) can do the tag list too. Just that i didn't know the specific word for it : ) . So I can work with this but what happens is when i select something from tag list it will made as a tag. So for example "Provider Address" is selected i cannot edit it further to add (= 10.0.0.0/24) where "=" also has to come from select options. Any more help would be much appreciated @briosheje :)

Comment: Where is this picture coming from? Link, please. What are **the requirements**? It's totally unclear. Don't answer in the comments. Edit the question instead

Comment: @x00 I dont have a link to it. It is a cisco server not available publically. Edit done!, If still not clear.

Comment: Have you considered anything like [chips](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-chips)?

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying to build is known as a Query Builder.

There are lots of query builders whose tags and list of conditions can be customized based on your needs.

One of them is - https://querybuilder.js.org/ - which use jQuery and Bootstrap.

Demo - https://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html

Here's an Angular Query Builder (my personal favorite due to the amount of customization you can do in this widget) - https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/demo/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Query Builder i have already seen, This is kind of an alternative to "option,tag,ul-li" based  query builder which i want. I want the same thing to be made using a simple text/select/tag input box.
Thanks for the effort. Would appreciate to point me to something similar to what i need.